# Periodical ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a google VM instance, created in `us-central1-f` region.
This machine has a cron job, that launches a dataproc cluster in `europe-west1-d` zone.

A command to create the cluster:

`gcloud dataproc clusters create ${name} --zone ${zone} --master-
machine-type n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size 100 --num-workers ${n_workers} --worker-machine-type n1-standard-16 --worker-boot-disk-size 64 --num-worker-local-ssds 1 --project ${proj_name}`

This job used to work ~6 month without any errors. But recently, 2-3 times a week it fails to start with an error `ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com`

Job starts at 1am UTC. When I relaunch it at 9am, it launches without any problems. Jobs in us-west and us-east regions are launched without any problems.

What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: Are you using a custom network config, and have you modified any firewall rules or network routes?

Comment: I use the default one, without any modifications or restrictions

Comment: Looks like this is an intermittent issue. Does this problem happen if you configure the cron job on a different VM instance?